# c++ linux: How can I trace the real reason of exception?

Tags: c++, linux

I got this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted
```

I have tried also with **gdb**, but with stack trace or logs of gdb, what only I can see is an error in **libc**. But I need to know the real reason that causes this: Who is causing std::string(NULL)?

How could I trace this?

**Edit:**

Here is the trace of gdb:

```
424backtrace
>&"backtrace\n"
>~"#0  0xb6dfd584 in raise () from /home/user0/device/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0\n"
>~"#1  0xb6df7888 in abort () from /home/user0/device/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0\n"
>~"#2  0xb6ea1398 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at /home/user0/Development/buildroot-2012.11.1/output/toolchain/gcc-4.8-20120429/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95\n"
>~"#3  0xb6e9f104 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at /home/user0/Development/buildroot-2012.11.1/output/toolchain/gcc-4.8-20120429/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:40\n"
>~"#4  0xb6e9f12c in std::terminate () at /home/user0/Development/buildroot-2012.11.1/output/toolchain/gcc-4.8-20120429/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:50\n"
>~"#5  0xb6edb064 in std::(anonymous namespace)::execute_native_thread_routine (__p=<optimized out>) at /home/user0/Development/buildroot-2012.11.1/output/toolchain/gcc-4.8-20120429/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:77\n"
>~"#6  0xb6fa2410 in start_thread () from /home/user0/device/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0\n"
>~"#7  0xb6dfcbd4 in clone () from /home/user0/device/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0\n"
>~"#8  0xb6dfcbd4 in clone () from /home/user0/device/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.0\n"
>~"Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)\n"
>424^done
```

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace you got from gdb?

Comment: Have you used the `bt` command in GDB?

Comment: I have run "backtrace" command and I have added its output to the question. I suppose that bt command is shortcut of backtrace.

Comment: The last line states `"Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)"`.  Are you sure you don't have undefined behaviour somewhere?

Comment: @G.M. What I got is that SIGABRT, which is caused by std::string. Because of this I have believed that some where std::string constructor receives null char pointer. Do you mean that maybe there is another error that causes this one?

Comment: @MertMertce Exactly that.  Throwing an uncaught exception and aborting on a call to std::string(nullptr) is reasonable enough but to get there (apparently) via a corrupt call stack does set off a few alarm bells.  By no means certain of course.

Comment: Actually, very probably this is caused by sqlite3-C library, but I could not see after which line of code (of mine) this occurs.

Comment: Did you try to check with *valgrind*?